# how can I find all member who are not in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT a.id, 
       a.driver_name, 
       a.route 
FROM assigns a 
INNER JOIN vehicles v ON a.id = v.assign_id NOT IN (vehicles)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know you tables structures but something like this.

```sql
SELECT a.id, 
       a.driver_name, 
       a.route 
FROM assigns a 
LEFT JOIN vehicles v ON (a.id = v.assign_id)
WHERE v.assign_id IS NULL
```

Comment: This one worked very wellthanks